# Textbox's Text and Datacontext binding in wpf through MVVM

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

.Xaml code:

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Name="txtRSINumber" Text="{Binding ListMembers.RSINumber,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DataContext="{Binding ListMembers, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
</TextBox>
```

MVVM class:

```
    public Member ListMembers
    {

        get
        {
            return _selectMember;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectMember = value;

            if (_selectMember.Id == 0)
            {
                ReadOnly();
                NotifyPropertyChanged("IsValidMember");
            }
            else
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ListMembers");


            }
        }
    }

    public string RSINumber
    {
        get { return _rsiNumber; }
        set
        {
            _rsiNumber = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("RSINumber");
            _member.RSINumber = value;
        }
    }
```

Problem: while datacontext binding is working but when i enter any text in text box RSINumber binding is not working.if i remove datacontext then it is working fine but i need both.

Comment: Why do you need to bind datacontext? Your Text binding should work fine on it's own.

Comment: i have data grid while click on that grid details of the controls should be filled up.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by binding the datacontext?

Comment: Have you implemented INotifyPropertyChanged in your datamodel (Member), and it's nested classes? You also need a twoway binding if you want to post changes in the GUI to affect your viewmodel. Add **Mode=TwoWay** in your TextBox Text Binding. Your datacontext there looks rather fishy. I would have used a ViewModelLocator from IE GalaSoft MVVM Light to set the datacontext on my view. Can you show us your Member class?